# HTTP Error 500 - typo3 - fresh install with template

Tags: php, typo3

I did a fresh installation of "typo3_src-11.5.12" and then I put this template over the installation ([Template](https://jweiland.net/typo3/typo3-template-version-11.html#c8464)). Backend works fine but the front end doesn't. Its shows this Error "Diese Seite funktioniert nicht briefbocks.de kann diese Anfrage momentan nicht verarbeiten. HTTP ERROR 500" - means "page not working".

So, I get this error:

> Core: Exception handler (WEB): Uncaught TYPO3 Exception: #500: Server error: `GET http://www.briefbocks.de/index.html` resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error` response | GuzzleHttp\Exception\ServerException thrown in file /mnt/web524/b3/46/52992746/htdocs/somefolder/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php in line 113. Requested URL: http://briefbocks.de/typo3/ajaxyoast/preview?token=--AnonymizedToken--&pageId=1&languageId=0&additionalGetVars=

Does anyone have any idea? I think I did something wrong ... Please help.

PHp-Version is 7.4, can be put to 8.0

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a PHP script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: Thx, its a commercial server, I don't have access to those logfiles.

Comment: Even commercial hosting gives you access to error files, unless you're dealing with a third party server. Contact your hosting company to find out how to access them.

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise to uninstall the yoast extension first, likely it's `yoast_seo`.
After that clear the cache and I suppose the frontend should run then.